# Can't Add Service Reference to self-hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wcf, wcf-client

I've created a REST web service that I need to consume from within an asp.net app. The service is hosted from a console window. I can get it running fine, and I can get output from it as well when surfing to it in a web browser. The problem is, when I try to "Add Service Reference" from my asp.net app, it complains of various things depending on which service URL I point it at. End result is I cannot figure out how to add the service reference.

My Interface is defined like so:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWave {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/devices")]
    List<Device> getDevices();

    ...
}
```

Here's how I'm hosting my service:

```
// Port is 1178
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}/wave", port));
var waveServiceSingleton = new WaveSVC();

binding = new WebHttpBinding();

var behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
behavior.FaultExceptionEnabled = true;

host = new WebServiceHost(waveServiceSingleton, endPoint.Uri);

// Get the service debug behavior and tell it to include details about errors
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb;
sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWave), binding, "");

// Add mex endpoint
ServiceMetadataBehavior mexBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
mexBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(mexBehavior);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWave), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), endPoint.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "/mex");

host.Open();
```

When I browse to http://localhost:1180/wave/devices, I see a json string in the body of my browser. This is expected and works as desired. I cannot point my "Add Service Reference" wizard to this URL, as it complains that:

```
The document at the url http://localhost:1178/wave/devices was not recognized as a known     document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position  1.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'.
  - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:1178/wave/devices'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I have a nagging suspicion that I need to point my "Add Service Reference" to the mex, but that doesn't work either and indeed, when I browse to the mex address of http://localhost:1178/wave/mex, I get a blank page.

**EDIT 1**

Just to eliminate JSON being the culprit, I changed my contract to output Xml instead of Json. The result was the same: I can't add a service reference using this URL: http://localhost:1178/zwave/devices/xml (even though that URL produces XML).

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate= "/devices/xml")]
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: BTW - have you tried using svcutil instead of VS to create a proxy from the mex data? from VS command prompt: svcutil.exe /o:client.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:1178/wave/mex

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the "add web reference" option you are using in Visual Studio is meant for referencing XML Web Services only. Your service is defined in terms of rest/json and not in terms of soap/xml/wsdl that visual studio expects.

I suspect that Visual Studio simply *isn't able to generate proxies for a json/rest service as yours*. This is confirmed in the documentation on the [WCF rest starter kit for .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx) (see the section "Consuming RESTful Services with HttpClient", search for "not possible to generate strongly-typed proxies like you’re used to with SOAP").

I'm not sure whether it is still unsupported in VS2010 / .NET 4.0, but I think you have to look for another option than "add web reference".

Comment: I changed my output to XML and I still cannot add a reference. It's roughly the same error. See my edit above for the changes I made.

Comment: Now it returns data in xml format, but Visual Studio still can't find the wsdl document needed for automatic proxy generation. And for REST services such a document doesn't exists, so I don't think this will work. I think the error message tries to inform you that VS cannot infer the wsdl from the data it receives.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps found for the blank page:

Replace

```
host = new WebServiceHost(waveServiceSingleton, endPoint.Uri);
```

with

```
host = new ServiceHost(waveServiceSingleton, endPoint.Uri);
```

this worked for me